# php - PDOException could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

I get PDOException could not find driver when connecting to mysql database with

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
```

on localhost on windows 10. I also tried replace localhost with 127.0.0.1.

phpinfo():
[image]

[image]

C:\php\php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "C:/php/ext"
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

php -m

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

C:\php\ext content:

```
25.10.2017  15:23            79 872 php_bz2.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            87 040 php_com_dotnet.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           478 208 php_curl.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            23 040 php_enchant.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            56 320 php_exif.dll
25.10.2017  15:23         2 874 880 php_fileinfo.dll
25.10.2017  15:23         1 504 768 php_gd2.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            48 128 php_gettext.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           359 936 php_gmp.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           911 360 php_imap.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            80 896 php_interbase.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           326 656 php_intl.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           218 624 php_ldap.dll
25.10.2017  15:23         1 413 632 php_mbstring.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            45 056 php_mysql.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           113 664 php_mysqli.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           147 456 php_oci8_12c.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           158 208 php_opcache.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           105 472 php_openssl.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            24 576 php_pdo_firebird.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            28 672 php_pdo_mysql.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            28 672 php_pdo_oci.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            24 576 php_pdo_odbc.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            39 936 php_pdo_pgsql.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           603 648 php_pdo_sqlite.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           117 760 php_pgsql.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            14 336 php_shmop.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           406 528 php_snmp.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           285 184 php_soap.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            68 608 php_sockets.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           761 856 php_sqlite3.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            38 912 php_sybase_ct.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           284 160 php_tidy.dll
25.10.2017  15:23            63 488 php_xmlrpc.dll
25.10.2017  15:23           285 696 php_xsl.dll
```

System Path:

```
C:\php
C:\php\ext
C:\Apache24
C:\Apache24/bin
```

Do I need any more drivers? Or is there any other problem?

If you need any more info I will provide it.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `;` from before the `;extension=php_pdo.dll`. And also from before other `pdo` extensions. If you want to use those. And then restart the server.

The `;` actually comments a line in `ini` files. So, you have to un-comment those lines to use them.

**Edit:** Instead of going through all of this trouble, you can instead use `Xampp` or `Wamp` or `EasyPHP` or something.

Comment: I un-commented extension=php_pdo.dl and it is still the same, even if I uncomment every extension.

Comment: yes, i did restart using httpd -k stop and httpd -k start in C:\Apache24\bin

Comment: PDO drivers mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite

Comment: Do you have `mysql` server installed?

Comment: yes, I can access phpMyAdmin and make database

Comment: Instead of all this trouble, why don't you use `Xampp` or `Wamp` or something? Also try using php builtin server instead of apache to test. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I will try Xampp. Do I need to remove current installations (and configurations) of apache and mysql and so on? or will Xampp manage everything?

Comment: Just export your db from mysql, and copy your php code. And if you want you can delete all this or keep it. But be sure to `stop` this `Apache` and `MySQL` instance.

Comment: Ok, I will remove them and try Xampp, thank you

Comment: @Spook If the answer was helpful please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove ; before `;extension=php_pdo.dll` and restart the Apache server.

Here `;` means commenting...so you need yo uncomment it by removing `;`.

Comment: I un-commented extension=php_pdo.dl and it is still the same, even if I uncomment every extension.

Comment: restarted apache???

Comment: yes, i did restart using httpd -k stop and httpd -k start in C:\Apache24\bin

Comment: can you check by hard coding host,dbname,username,password          
         $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password); in this

Comment: new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_iis", "user", "user");

Comment: did u checked with above on???

Comment: yes, i did, still the same error

Comment: service apache2 restart try this to restart apache